# Rails I18n - model validation return [object Object]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, model, internationalization

Example of validation rule:

```
  validates :first_name, :presence => {:message => I18n.t('activerecord.errors.models.user.required_item')}, :allow_blank => true, :length => {:minimum => 3, :maximum => 40}
```

Locale:

```
de:
  activerecord:
      errors:
        models:
          user:
            povinne_pole:
              required_item: "error message" # see default key: "inclusion"
```

Returns

```
[object Object]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Returns where? `[object Object]` looks more like something from JavaScript than Ruby.

Comment: returns in the browser. I use `client_side_validation` gem for the form.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `povinne_pole` in I18n.t call.